# Serve local files via a URL in R

Tags: r, servr

I have a R package [safedata](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/safedata/index.html) that is used to manage research data stored on Zenodo. It communicates with Zenodo to retrieve data but also a separate metadata server.

For code examples (and probably also package testing), it would be really useful to be able to temporarily switch the URL of the metadata server to a server created using `servr` and then fake the responses of that metadata server using static local files in the package `inst` directory.

I can't quite get it to work. The served directory is available via a browser - so for example http://127.0.0.1:4321/api/index.json loads just fine - but if I try and access that URL from within R using `httr::GET` then it hangs without returning content.

I may be seriously overcomplicating things and missing a simpler option for accessing a local file via a URL?

Comment: To add - I've looked at [webfakes](https://webfakes.r-lib.org/) and also [webmockr](https://docs.ropensci.org/webmockr/). Those are both neat - and have the advantage that I can mock more URI details such as the query - but I'd need to manually set up all the URIs to mock. I was hoping `servr` would allow me to automatically expose a directory tree via a URL.